# Guardar dados de um webservice numa variável global em Android

Tags: android, web-service

eu estou iniciando com a programação Android e estou tendo um problema. Eu gostaria de armazenar a resposta do meu webservice em uma variável global. Esse webservice retorna um valor boolean, esse valor eu gostaria de armazenar na variável global conectado. Porém da maneira como eu fiz, abaixo, ao deixar a classe ConectaBdTask essa variável [conectado] continua sempre false. Eu já executei no modo Debug e o retorno do webservice é true. Vocês poderiam me ajudar a resolver esse problema? Grato!

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean conectado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        conectado = false;
        new ConectaBdTask().execute();
    }


    private class ConectaBdTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        //quando doInBackground termina, é chamado o onPostExecute com o retorno do doInBackground
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final String url = "localhost/conectarBd";
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

                //faz a requisição ao Web Service
                Boolean conectado = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Boolean.class);

                return conectado;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean conectado) {

            LoginActivity.this.conectado = conectado;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Procure SharedPreferences android no google, é uma das maneiras mais faceis de fazer isso.

Comment: me parece bom, mas não dá para guardar objetos

Comment: Mas é só voce guarda o valor boolean e verifica se ele é verdadeiro, marca senão deixa desmarcado. Uso esse exemplo para ver se a pessoa deixou um checkbox que salva a senha na minha tela de login.

Comment: É verdade, obrigado pela dica Bruno.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fala Gabriel,

Você deve criar uma classe que extenda **Application**, exemplo:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private String someVariable;

    public String getSomeVariable() {
        return someVariable;
    }

    public void setSomeVariable(String someVariable) {
        this.someVariable = someVariable;
    }
}
```

Lá no seu AndroidManifest.xml, você deve alterar o nome da tag application, dessa forma:

```
<application 
  android:name=".MyApplication" 
  android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Depois, pra setar uma váriavel, use:

```
// set
((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).setSomeVariable("foo");
```

E para resgatá-la em qualquer lugar da aplicação, use:

```
// get
String s = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getSomeVariable();
```

Abraços.

Comment: Não tem como guardar essa resposta direto numa variável global?

Comment: Fala Gabriel, tem sim, eu editei minha resposta, da uma olhada. Abraços.

Comment: Valeu Leonardo, muito obrigado!! Vou testar e ver se funciona. Só mas uma pergunta, teria como eu guardar a resposta do webservice diretamente naquela variável global chamada conectado?

Comment: @GabrielOliveira Se ela fosse estática, sim. Como pertence ao objeto e não à classe, quando o objeto morrer ela morre junto (o objeto no caso é a instância de `LoginActivity`, que quando você virar o celular de lado por exemplo vai ser substituída por outra instância). Ah, e se a sua aplicação ficar um tempo inativa e o sistema operacional decidir matá-la para economizar recursos, o que é muito frequente, ela morre também, sendo estática ou não.

Comment: Ah entendi, Piovezan. Muito Obrigado pessoal! Testei o que o Leonardo falor e funcionou muito bem, resolveu meu problema!

Answer (score 1):

Podes criar uma class singleton e guardar lá os dados, tenho uma class desse genero aqui

https://github.com/xanexpt/flickr/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/badjoras/baamflickr/AppSingleton.java

nessa class crias getters e setters para as variaveis que queres guardar, depois podes aceder "em qualquer" lado desta maneira

```
AppSingleton.getInstance().setAdsResponse(response.body());
AppSingleton.getInstance().getAdsById(adId);
```

EDIT:
Não faças como diz na resposta anterior, guardar coisas na class Application é alto martelo...

Comment: Bem vindo ao site, antes de uma olhada no http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e melhore sua pergunta para melhor ser ajudado

Comment: eu nao fiz perguntas @MarceloDiniz , eu estou a dar respostas.
A resposta que foi aceite como correta, é como nos os programadores chamamos martelar codigo, funciona mas está mal feito